# Changing html element attribute using vue $refs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to access the href attribute of a link element in a distant componant.
The @click func will generate a new href and then place it in the link element.

Here is my current link:

```
 <a ref="svglink" href="javascript:void(0)"  @click="saveSvg2" download="testSvg.svg" >EXPORT SVG</a>
```

I try to place the new url like this:

````
this.$refs.svglink.href = url;
```
But I get a "Property 'href' does not exist on type 'Vue'" message from my IDE and the code is not working.

What am I doing wrong?
````

Comment: To use ref you have to put `ref="svglink"` instead of `id`

Comment: Sorry for the ugly typo, I have corrected it but the problem remains the same.

Comment: where are you using `$refs` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `ref="svglink"` instead of `id="svglink"` if you want to use a ref.

However, there's a better way than this by using reactive properties.

```html
<template>
  <a id="svglink" :href="url"  @click="saveSvg2" download="testSvg.svg" >EXPORT SVG</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // whenever you update this.url the link will update
    // doesn't have to be in mounted(), this is just an example
    this.url = 'http://example.com'
  }
}
</script>
```